# Cannot retrieve data via checkbox in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, checkbox, laravel-blade

I have a project in which i want to retrieve value from database via checkbox. But i cannot do this.
My controller code is

```
public function browseProfessionals() {
        $userRoles = UserRole::whereIn('role_id', [2,3])->get();
        $users = array();
        $showUsers = array();

        foreach ($userRoles as $userRole) {
            $users[] = User::find($userRole->user_id);
        }

        $valid_providers = array();
        $all_providers = array();
        $user_role_all_providers = UserRole::where('role_id', 2)->get();

        foreach ($user_role_all_providers as $user_role_all_provider) {
            $all_providers[] = User::where('id', $user_role_all_provider->user_id)->first();
        }

        foreach ($all_providers as $all_provider) {
            $user = User::where('id', $all_provider->id)->first();
            $user_detail = UserDetail::where('user_id', $all_provider->id)->first();
            $user_meeting = UserMeeting::where('user_id', $all_provider->id)->first();
            $user_time = UserTime::where('user_id', $all_provider->id)->first();

            if (!empty($user_detail->avatar) && !empty($user_meeting->meeting_id) && !empty($user_time->hour_rate) && $user->is_active == 1 && $user->is_deleted == 0) {
                $valid_providers[] = $all_provider;
            }
        }

        $data = [
            'valid_providers' => $showUsers,
            'industries' => Industry::where('is_active', 1)->where('is_deleted', 0)->get(),
            'degrees' => UserDegree::where('degree_id', $user->degree_id)->get(),
        ];
        return view('frontends.browse-professionals', $data);
    }
```

My Blade template is

```
@extends ('frontends.layouts.app')
@section ('main')
    <div id="content-block" class="margin-top-140">
        <div class="container-fluid block custom-container">
            <h3 class="block-title">Browse Professionals</h3>
            <div class="block-subtitle"><span>Connect</span> <span>Learn</span> <span>Inspire</span> <span>Thrive</span> </div>
            <div class="row">
                {{--<form action="" method="post">--}}
                    <div class="col-md-2 left-feild">
                        <div class="margin-bottom-30">
                            <h3>Search Filters</h3>
                        </div>
                        @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->user_role->role_id == 1000000)
                            <div class="be-vidget">
                                <h3 class="letf-menu-article"> Looking To </h3>
                                <div class="creative_filds_block">
                                    <div class="radio">
                                        <label><input type="radio" name="lookingTo" onclick="lookingTo(2)"> Seek Advice</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="radio">
                                        <label><input type="radio" name="lookingTo" onclick="lookingTo(3)"> Share Advice</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <script>
                                function lookingTo(e) {
                                    $.ajax({
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        url: '{{ URL::to('looking/to') }}/' + e,
                                        success: function (result) {
                                            $('#browse_professionals').html(result);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            </script>
                        @endif
                        <div class="be-vidget">
                            <h3 class="letf-menu-article">Professionals</h3>
                            <div class="-creative_filds_block">
                                <div class="fp-panel-wrap">
                                    <a class="toggle-btn active" onclick="open_industry()" href="#" data-target="#ul_industry" id="a_industry">Industry</a>
                                    <ul id="ul_industry" class="fp-panel open" style="overflow:scroll; height:200px;">
                                        @if(!empty($industries))
                                            @foreach($industries as $industry)
                                                <li value="{{ $industry->id }}"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="industry_search({{ $industry->id }})">{{ (!empty($industry['name'])) ? $industry['name'] : '' }}</a> </li>
                                            @endforeach
                                        @endif
                                    </ul>
                                    <script>
                                        function industry_search(e) {
                                            $.ajax({
                                                type: 'POST',
                                                url: '{{ URL::to('professionals/industry') }}/' + e,
                                                success: function (result) {
                                                    $('#education_experience').html(result);
                                                    $('#a_industry').attr('class', 'toggle-btn');
                                                    $('#ul_industry').css('display', 'none');
                                                    $('#education_experience').css('display', 'block');
                                                    $('#eduLevel').css('display', 'block');
                                                    $('#areaExperience').css('display', 'block');

                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                        function open_industry() {
                                            $('#education_experience').css('display', 'block'); // display none hobe na. collapse hoye jabe
//                                        $('#a_industry').attr('class', 'toggle-btn active');
//                                        $('#ul_industry').css('display', 'block');
                                            $('#education_experience').css('display', 'block');
                                            $('#eduLevel').css('display', 'none');
                                            $('#areaExperience').css('display', 'none');
                                        }
                                    </script>
                                    <div id="education_experience" style="">
                                        <a id="a_education" class="toggle-btn" href="#" data-target="#eduLevel">Education Level</a>
                                        <ul id="eduLevel" class="no-link fp-panel" style="overflow:scroll; height:200px;">


                                            @if(!empty($degrees))
                                                @foreach($degrees as $degree)
                                                    <li value="{{ $degree->id }}">{{ (!empty($degree['name'])) ? $degree['name'] : '' }}</a> </li>
                                                @endforeach
                                            @endif

                                        </ul>
                                        <a id="a_experience" class="toggle-btn" href="#" data-target="#areaExperience">Areas of Experience</a>
                                        <ul id="areaExperience" class="no-link fp-panel" style="overflow:scroll; height:200px;">

                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="be-vidget">
                            <h3 class="letf-menu-article">Meeting Preferences</h3>
                            <label>Price</label>
                            <br> <br>
                            <input type="hidden" id="price_ranger" class="range-slider" value="23"/>


                            <label style="margin-top: 30px;">Type</label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select class="form-input" id="meeting_type">
                                    <option value="3">All</option>
                                    <option value="1">Phone Meeting</option>
                                    <option value="2">Web Meeting</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <button id="search_professionals" type="button" class="btn color-2 size-2 btn-block hover-1">Apply Filter</button>
                        @if(Session::has('remove_filter'))
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger size-2 btn-block hover-1">Remove Filter</button>
                        @endif

                        <script>
                            var industry = '';
                            $('#ul_industry li').click(function() {
                                industry = $(this).attr('value');
                            });

                            $("#search_professionals").click(function () {
                                var degrees = new Array();
                                $('input[name="degrees_checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
                                    degrees.push(this.value);
                                });

                                var experiences = new Array();
                                $('input[name="experiences_checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
                                    experiences.push(this.value);
                                });

                                var price_ranger = $("#price_ranger").val();
                                var price_ranger_array = price_ranger.split(",");
                                var start_price = price_ranger_array[0];
                                var end_price = price_ranger_array[1];

                                var meeting_type = $("#meeting_type").val();

                                $.ajax({
                                    'type' : 'post',
                                    'url' : '{{ URL::to('search/professionals') }}',
                                    'data' : {
                                        'industry' : industry,
                                        'educationLevels' : degrees,
                                        'areasOfExperiences' : experiences,
                                        'start_price' : start_price,
                                        'end_price' : end_price,
                                        'meeting_type' : meeting_type
                                    },
                                    'success' : function (result) {
                                        console.log(result);
                                        $('#browse_professionals').html(result);
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
                    </div>
                {{--</form>--}}

                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div id="browse_professionals" class="row _post-container_">
                        @if (!empty($valid_providers))
                            @foreach ($valid_providers as $provider)

                                <div class="category-1 custom-column-5">
                                    <div class="be-post">
                                        <figure class="ratio-4-3 be-img-block-alt">
                                            <div class="ratio-inner" style="background-image: url('{{ !empty($provider->user_detail->avatar) ? URL::to($provider->user_detail->avatar) : '' }}')">
                                                <img src="{{ !empty($provider->user_detail->avatar) ? URL::to($provider->user_detail->avatar) : '' }}" alt="{{ !empty($provider->username) ? URL::to($provider->username) : '' }}">
                                            </div>
                                        </figure>
                                        <div class="be-post-title">{{ (!empty($provider->user_share->share)) ? str_limit($provider->user_share->share, 90) : '' }}</div>
                                        <div class="author-post">
                                            <span><a href="{{ !empty($provider->username) ? URL::to($provider->username) : '' }}">{{ !empty($provider->user_detail->first_name) ? $provider->user_detail->first_name : '' }} {{ !empty($provider->user_detail->last_name) ? $provider->user_detail->last_name : '' }}</a></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <span>{{ (!empty($provider->user_detail->credentials)) ? str_limit($provider->user_detail->credentials, 25) : '' }}</span>
                                        <div data-value="4" class="static-rating"></div>
                                        <div class="info-block clearfix">
                                            <a class="btn color-1 size-2 hover-1 pull-right" href="{{ !empty($provider->username) ? URL::to($provider->username) : '' }}">Contact</a>
                                            <h3 class="rate"> ${{ (!empty($provider->user_time->hour_rate)) ? $provider->user_time->hour_rate : '' }} /hr</h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            @endforeach
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

My Searchcontroller is

```
public function searchProfessionals (Request $request)
    {
        $industry = $request->input('industry');
        $educationLevels = $request->input('educationLevels');
        $areasOfExperiences = $request->input('areasOfExperiences');
        $startPrice = $request->input('start_price');
        $endPrice = $request->input('end_price');
        $meetingType = $request->input('meeting_type');

        if ($meetingType == 1) {
            $type = [1, 1];
        } elseif ($meetingType == 2) {
            $type = [2, 2];
        } elseif ($meetingType === 3) {
            $type = [1, 2];
        } else {
            $type = [1, 2];
        }

        $userMeetings = array();
        $userRoles = array();
        $users = array();
        $showUsers = array();
        $userHourRates = array();
//        return response($industry);

        $userIndus = UserIndustry::where('industry_id', $industry)->get();

        if (!empty($userIndus)) {
            foreach ($userIndus as $userInd) {
                $userHourRates = UserTime::where('user_id', $userInd->user_id)->whereBetween('hour_rate', [$startPrice, $endPrice])->first();
            }

//        $userHourRates = UserTime::whereBetween('hour_rate', [$startPrice, $endPrice])->get();
            if (!empty($userHourRates)) {
                foreach ($userHourRates as $userHourRate) {
                    $userMeetings[] = UserMeeting::whereIn('meeting_id', $type)->where('user_id', $userHourRate->user_id)->first();
                }
                if (!empty($userMeetings)) {

                    foreach ($userMeetings as $userMeeting) {
                        $userRoles[] = UserRole::where('user_id', $userMeeting['user_id'])->where('role_id', '!=', 1)->first();
                    }
                    if (!empty($userRoles)) {
                        foreach ($userRoles as $userRole) {
                            $users[] = User::find($userRole['user_id']);
                        }
                        if (!empty($users)) {
                            foreach ($users as $u) {
                                $user = User::find($u['id']);
                                $userDetail = UserDetail::where('user_id', $u['id'])->first();
                                $userShare = UserShare::where('user_id', $u['id'])->first();
                                $userMeeting = UserMeeting::where('user_id', $u['id'])->first();
                                $userWeek = UserWeek::where('user_id', $u['id'])->first();
                                $userTime = UserTime::where('user_id', $u['id'])->first();
                                if (
                                    $user['is_active'] == 1 && $user['is_deleted'] == 0 && !empty($userDetail['avatar']) && !empty($userDetail['first_name']) &&
                                    !empty($userDetail['last_name']) && !empty($userDetail['credentials']) && !empty($userShare['share']) &&
                                    !empty($userShare['seek']) && !empty($userMeeting['meeting_id']) && !empty($userWeek['week_id']) &&
                                    !empty($userTime['start_time']) && !empty($userTime['end_time']) && !empty($userTime['hour_rate'])
                                ) {
                                    $showUsers[] = $u;
                                }
                            }
                            if (!empty($showUsers)) {
                                $string = '';
                                foreach ($showUsers as $showUser) {
                                    $userShow = User::find($showUser->id);
                                    $userDetailShow = UserDetail::where('user_id', $showUser->id)->first();
                                    $userShareShow = UserShare::where('user_id', $showUser->id)->first();
                                    $userRatingShow = Review::where('provider_id', $showUser->id)->orWhere('seeker_id', $showUser->id)->avg('rating');
                                    $userTimeShow = UserTime::where('user_id', $showUser->id)->first();
                                    $string .= '
                                <div class="category-1 custom-column-5">
                                    <div class="be-post">
                                        <figure class="ratio-4-3 be-img-block-alt">
                                            <div class="ratio-inner" style="background-image: url(' . url($userDetailShow->avatar) . ')">
                                                <img src="' . url($userDetailShow->avatar) . '" alt="omg">
                                            </div>
                                        </figure>
                                        <div class="be-post-title">' . str_limit($userShareShow->share, 90) . '</div>
                                        <div class="author-post">
                                            <span>
                                                <a href="' . url($userShow->username) . '">' .
                                        $userDetailShow->first_name . ' ' . $userDetailShow->last_name . '
                                                </a>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                        <span>' . $userDetailShow->credentials . '</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div data-value="' . $userRatingShow . '" class="static-rating"></div>
                                        <div class="info-block clearfix">
                                            <a class="btn color-1 size-2 hover-1 pull-right" href="' . url($userShow->username) . '">Contact</a>
                                            <h3 class="rate">$' . $userTimeShow->hour_rate . '/hr</h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            ';
                                }
                                return response($string);
                            } else {
                                return 'data not found.';
                            }
                        } else {
                            return 'data not found.';
                        }
                    } else {
                        return 'data not found.';
                    }

                } else {
                    return 'data not found.';
                }
            } else {
                return 'data not found.';
            }
        } else {
            return 'data not found.';
        }
    }
```

Please help me how can i show value via checkbox. Please help me solving this.

Comment: what checkbox?...i don't even see one in your html anywhere. Please only post  code relevant to the specific problem. We don't need to see all sorts of unrelated elements and script. Also take a few minutes to review [ask]. Your specific problem and question are not very clear. *'i cannot do this"* does not tell us very much

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug your JavaScript by F12, and notice there is any error or not.
if not there is no Javascript problem, you can also check ajax request return data on network tab.

Comment: Its javascript problem. The data cannot be viewed as shown in the database. Its data cannot be viewed as the javascript is called for. Would you please help me fixing this @ThaTal

Comment: Sorry bro u have too many ajax requst. I suggest you to try every ajax request. One by one. So it will help you. Test in every step.